# Concerns with working as a Teenager

Tags: united-states, minor, labor-law, washington, work-for-hire

I am a 13 year old. I am wanting to work at my town's local book shop. I live in Washington, USA. I can't find any online documents regarding if I can or cannot work there.

According to official D.O.L. documents, if you're 13 you can only work *only* on farming or other *non harmful* jobs. I was wondering if working at a produce store/book store is considered a "safe" job and if so, I can still get the minimum `$7.25` pay since I am still working, right?

Also, the D.O.L. documents say overtime **doesn't apply** to farm jobs. Does the produce store job count as working on an "active farm", since the store *does* handle and process fruits, vegetables and farming related items but **doesn't** grow them.

Comment: You'd have to check Child Labor Laws in your state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Washington State Department of Labor & Industries](https://www.lni.wa.gov/workers-rights/youth-employment/hours-of-work),

> Under 14 years old
> In most cases, you need a superior court’s permission for minors under 14 to work. Minors under 14 who are allowed to work must follow the 14-15 year old requirements below.

Which may or may not be easy to get.

Also:

> **For Employers**
>
> Employers must complete and sign a Parent/School Authorization form before giving it to the teen’s parents and the school the teen attends for their signatures. The form must be renewed annually by Sept. 30.
>
> Employers also must have a minor work permit. This permit is available from the state Department of Revenue/Business License Service and must be renewed every year.
>
> Employers can obtain a minor work variance to extend daily and total hours per week with an application to L&I.

So there's some extra paperwork all-around.